# Kernel source rpm CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, rhel, centos6

I have CentOS 6.3 installed.

## cat /etc/redhat-release

CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

## uname -mrs

Linux **2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64** x86_64

I am following the steps outlined in the following links to fetch and build the kernel (to enable certain features):
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel

In the CentOS 6.3 vault (http://vault.centos.org/6.3/updates/Source/SPackages/), following kernel source rpms are listed:

```
kernel-2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.src.rpm
kernel-2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.src.rpm
kernel-2.6.32-279.5.1.el6.src.rpm
kernel-2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.src.rpm
kernel-2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.src.rpm
kernel-2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.src.rpm
kernel-2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.src.rpm
kernel-2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.src.rpm
kernel-2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.src.rpm
```

I am trying to find out, which of the above source rpm corresponds to kernel version **2.6.32-279.el6**  (output of "uname -r" which does not contain the additional 2 digits of the version number in the list above).  Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 4):

After much wrecking my head and tons of googling (which did not shed any light), I finally figured out the answer to my question.  I will state my answer using CentOS 6.3 as a example, same logic applies to CentOS 6.4.  If one has a fresh install of CentOS 6.3, look for the kernel source file at the following site:

http://vault.centos.org/6.3/**os**/Source/SPackages/

The above site contains only one kernel source rpm (for kernel with the version number that does not contain the two additional digits in the version number).  Not confusion there.

However, if one has applied a patch to the stock 6.3 release, then depending on the patch level, the kernel version is extended (with the two digits) for which the corresponding kernel source is available at the following site:

http://vault.centos.org/6.3/**updates**/Source/SPackages/

--Ahmed.

Comment: In addition, for buildling external modules in Centos 6.3 , this may help...http://rhel-internal.blogspot.in/2013/06/rebuilding-kernel-2632-279el6x8664.html